# twitteR and ROAuth with as.environment error

Tags: r, twitter, roauth

I am very new to the Twitter environment.  I am trying to analyse Twitter messages using twitteR.  I am having trouble with the ROauth package.  I followed the instructions in the ROAuth package documentation but I still get an error message.  Here is what I do and the message I get.

```
> reqURL <-"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
> authURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
> accessURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
> cKey <- "xxxxxxxx"
> cSecret <- "xxxxxxxxxx"
> credentials <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerkey=cKey, 
 consumerSecret=cSecret,requestURL=reqURL, accessURL=accessURL, authURL=authURL)
```

**Error in as.environment(x) : invalid object for 'as.environment'**

I tried changing the https to http but nothing changed.  My session information is as follows:

```
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_South Africa.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_South Africa.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_South Africa.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                         
[5] LC_TIME=English_South Africa.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ROAuth_0.9.3   digest_0.6.2   RCurl_1.95-4.1 bitops_1.0-5  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.15.2
```

I also installed R version 3.0.1 but I had the same issue.  Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead of all of that jazz:

```
cred = getTwitterOAuth(YOURKEY, YOURSECRET)
```

This simplifies the process and manages to cut out a lot of errors caused by small differences

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I tried your recommendation but I still get the as.environment error I described in my question.  I thought it had something to do with my company's firewall and tried wi-fi.  Same problem.  So I cannot get past the credentials step.

Comment: I managed to sort the problem out.  I upgraded to R Version 3.0.1 and installed the latest version of all the packages needed.  The error did not appear again.

Comment: I see a lot of users talk about `download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem",
          destfile="cacert.pem")
twitCred$handshake(cainfo="cacert.pem")`.  This is not part of the getTwitterOAuth package.  Does this matter?

Comment: @Hein that is the root certificates which are taken from Firefox. If you are happy to use them it is fine. Did it fix your problem?